# SQL Join query to show records if exists in master table or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table1

```
id name color 
1,'a','red'
2,'a','blue'
3,'b','red'
4,'c','red'
5,'d','red'
6,'a','green'

declare @t1 table (id int, name varchar(10),color varchar(5))
insert into @t1 values(1,'a','red')
insert into @t1 values(2,'a','blue')
insert into @t1 values(3,'b','red')
insert into @t1 values(4,'c','red')
insert into @t1 values(5,'d','red')
```

table t2 (master table )

```
color 
red
blue
green

declare @t2 table (color varchar(5))
insert into @t2 values ('red')
insert into @t2 values ('blue')
insert into @t2 values ('green')
```

The output will be

```
'a','red'
'a','blue'
'a','green'
```

We need to retrieve the name from table 1 what are all having all the t2 color...

Comment: Do you really want three rows of results or just the names that match the condition?

Comment: Hi Gordon, I need three rows..

Answer (score 4):

You can get the names in `t1` that match *all* master colors using `group by`, `having`, and `join`:

```
select t1.name
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.color = t2.color
group by t1.name
having count(distinct t1.color) = (select count(*) from t2);
```

This returns the names.  If you want the detailed rows, then use this as a subquery or CTE and join `t1` back to these results.

And to get the detailed rows:

```
with n as (
      select t1.name
      from t1 join
           t2
           on t1.color = t2.color
      group by t1.name
      having count(distinct t1.color) = (select count(*) from t2)
     )
select t1.*
from t1 join
     n
     on t1.name = n.name;
```

Comment: Thanks! In the last line of the query, it will be _"having count(distinct t1.color) = (select count(*) from t2);"_